# Export data from SQL Server table TO DBF file

Tags: sql-server, datatable

I want to convert SQL Server table data to `.DBF` file.

Below query is working without date. But when I add date it's not working. Please solve my issue, thanks in advance.

Without date:

```
INSERT INTO Fe130328.DBF (LINENO, BOOK, VCHSERIES, VCHNO, ACCODE, ACHEAD, CITY, NARRATION, DEBIT,CREDIT) 
VALUES ('" & str_sr_no & "','" & str_book & "','" & str_vchseries & "','" & str_vchno & "','" & str_accode & "','" & str_achead & "','" & str_city & "','" & str_narration & "','" & str_debit & "','" & str_credit & "')"
```

With date:

```
INSERT INTO Fe130328.DBF (LINENO, DATE, BOOK, VCHSERIES, VCHNO, ACCODE, ACHEAD, CITY, NARRATION, DEBIT, CREDIT) 
VALUES ('" & str_sr_no & "','21/07/2020','" & str_book & "','" & str_vchseries & "','" & str_vchno & "','" & str_accode & "','" & str_achead & "','" & str_city & "','" & str_narration & "','" & str_debit & "','" & str_credit & "')"
```

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should ***NEVER EVER*** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection - check out [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Date value should be **MM/DD/YYYY** format. Just make change Date format and use following query.

```
INSERT INTO Fe130328.DBF (LINENO, DATE, BOOK, VCHSERIES, VCHNO, ACCODE, ACHEAD, CITY, NARRATION, DEBIT, CREDIT) 
VALUES ('" & str_sr_no & "','07/21/2020','" & str_book & "','" & str_vchseries & "','" & str_vchno & "','" & str_accode & "','" & str_achead & "','" & str_city & "','" & str_narration & "','" & str_debit & "','" & str_credit & "')"
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, Error Msg. Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement.

Comment: It`s OK. but if you got help then you may upvote also.